# get value of selected checkbox in kivy

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

## test.py

```
import sqlite3 as lite

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (600, 325)

class UserGroup(Screen):

    def insert_data(self, arg1,arg2):
        print(arg1)
        print(arg2)


class FactUserGroup(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FactUserGroup().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.120

UserGroup

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 20, 20
        row_default_height: '30dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Male'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id : chk


        Label:
            text: 'Female'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'age'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: age


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'
            on_press: root.insert_data(chk.text,age.text)


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

How to get value of checkbox?I am getting value of age textbox using age.text but checkbox value i don't know? 
When click on 'Ok' then How to get selected checkbox value and pass in root.insert_data.

Comment: Have you tried `chk.active`? See https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.checkbox.html as reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the checked state of a checkbox with its `active` property, so try change:

```
GreenButton:
    text: 'Ok'
    on_press: root.insert_data(chk.active ,age.text)
```

In this snippet `chk.text` was changed to `chk.active` which works for me properly.

See more reference on kivy checkboxes at https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.checkbox.html

Hope it helps. Give it a try.

## UPDATE:

So in order to be able to get the properties of each checkbox and the text input you can assign `ObjectProperties` to the widgets, and you can link them to your `test.py` file.

The modified sources:

### test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Window.size = (600, 325)

class UserGroup(Screen):
    male = ObjectProperty(None)
    female = ObjectProperty(None)
    age = ObjectProperty(None)
    
    def insert_data(self):
        if self.male.active:
            print('Male')
        elif self.female.active:
            print('Female')
        else:
            print('No gender selected')
        print(self.age.text)


class FactUserGroup(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FactUserGroup().run()
```

In the `.py` file you can find a new import of `ObjectProperty`.
Also you can see that three new properties were defined in `UserGroup` to interact with the view, and the modifications in `UserGroup.insert_data` are straightforward.

### test.kv

```
<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.120

UserGroup

    male: chk_male
    female: chk_female
    age: txt_age

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 20, 20
        row_default_height: '30dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Male'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id : chk_male

        Label:
            text: 'Female'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id: chk_female

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'age'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: txt_age


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'
            on_press: root.insert_data()


        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

In the `.kv` file the ids of the two checkboxes and the text input are renamed to `chk_male`, `chk_female` and `txt_age` respectively.

Also you can see that the object property links are defined at the beginning of the `UserGroup` section.

Hope it makes sense and match your requirements.

Comment: Can you give me one more favour?Its print true false but i want male,female value.

Comment: Well you grouped the checkboxes so only one can be active at a time. `chk` is the `id` of the male checkbox, so when you get `True` the male is selected, and when you get `False` than the female one is selected.

Comment: If i don't select anyone then also will get value false.

Comment: @gunjantalwar that's true, I will update my answer to introduce you a different and more robust approach.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use ***StringProperty***, add ***text*** (Male, Female) to CheckBox, and ***on_active*** event to capture the gender.

### test.py

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
...
    def insert_data(self, age):
        print("Gender={}".format(self.gender))
        print("Age={}".format(age))
```

### test.kv

```
        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id : chk
            text: "Male"
            on_active:
                root.gender = self.text
        ...
        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            text: "Female"
            on_active:
                root.gender = self.text
        ...
        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'
            on_press: root.insert_data(age.text)
```

## Example

### test.py

```
import sqlite3 as lite

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.size = (600, 325)


class UserGroup(Screen):
    gender = StringProperty("")

    def insert_data(self, age):
        print("Gender={}".format(self.gender))
        print("Age={}".format(age))


class FactUserGroup(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    FactUserGroup().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.120

UserGroup

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 20, 20
        row_default_height: '30dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Male'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            id : chk
            text: "Male"
            on_active:
                root.gender = self.text

        Label:
            text: 'Female'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        CheckBox:
            group: 'check'
            text: "Female"
            on_active:
                root.gender = self.text

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'age'
            text_size: self.size
            valign: 'middle'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: age

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'
            on_press: root.insert_data(age.text)

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - Male & Age 21]
[image: Figure 2 - Female & Age 20]