# Save checkbox data and textinput data to .Json file

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

Im trying to save data from one page of my app into a .json file. There are 2 checkboxes and one text input area. I only wish to save one or the other as not all of them need to be saved. Just the selected one.

Ive tried reading the kivy docs, and ive tried various examples from here and on the web, and i still cannot save my data as intended into a json file.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.properties import ListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.clock import Clock

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class FirstScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Who(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Who, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.store = JsonStore("who.json")
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda *args: self.load())

    def save(self):
        self.store.put('who',
            mum = self.mum.checkbox,
            dad = self.dad.checkbox,
            other = self.other.text)

    def load(self):
        if self.store.exists('who'):
            who = self.store.get('who')
            w = [("mum", self.mum), ("dad", self.dad), ("other", self.other)]
            for key, ti in v:
                val = who.get(key)
                if val:
                    ti.text = val

root_widget = Builder.load_file("test.kv")

runTouchApp(root_widget)
```

and my kv doc looks like this:

```
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import StringProperty kivy.properties.StringProperty
#:import ObjectProperty kivy.properties.ObjectProperty
#:import Label kivy.uix.label.Label
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
#:import ListProperty kivy.properties.ListProperty
#:import CheckBox kivy.uix.checkbox.CheckBox
#:import TextInput kivy.uix.textinput.TextInput
#:import Button kivy.uix.button.Button
#:import BoxLayout kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout
#:import GridLayout kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout
#:import CheckBox kivy.uix.checkbox.CheckBox

MyScreenManager:

    transition: FadeTransition()
    Who:
    FirstScreen:

<Who>:
    name: 'who'   

    mum: mum
    dad: dad
    other: other

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        row_force_default: True
        row_default_height: '50dp'

        Label:
            text: 'Mum'
            font_size: 30

        CheckBox:
            id: mum
            on_press: root.save(mum.active, mum.text)

        Label:
            text: 'Dad'
            font_size: 30

        CheckBox:
            id: dad
            on_press: root.save(dad.active, dad.text)

        Label:
            text: 'Someone Else'
            font_size: 30

        TextInput:
            id: other
            multiline: False
            font_size: 30

        Button:
            text: 'Book'
            font_size: 30
            valign: 'middle'
            on_press: root.save()

        Button:
            text: 'Cancel'
            font_size: 30
            valign: 'middle'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'first'

<FirstScreen>:
    name: 'first'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Go Back'
            font_size: 40
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Back To Who'
                font_size: 40
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'who'
```

The outcome usually revolves around this:

File "kivy/weakproxy.pyx", line 30, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.**getattr**
 AttributeError: 'CheckBox' object has no attribute 'text'

---

Expected outcome is obviously saved json data. I need to be able to select one or the other or even all at once. I have tried all I can find. My cat is scared of me. I need help. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47389711/7505395) you might want to _group_ your checkboxes so only one can be active - beside that - a checkbox has no `.text` attribute - you could use the labels `.text` - for that you give then an `id` and ask them about their `.text` - or simply hardwire strings into `.save` that checkbox is `.active` : `on_press: root.save(dad.active, 'dad')`

Comment: Thank you for that Patrick. I will try out your result.

Comment: So I managed to find a solution. It was the fact that I hadnt used the .active tag within my def save area. The syntax was wrong. It is supposed to go self.store.put('save', mum = self.mum.active) The .kv document was simply to reflect as: CheckBox: id: mum active:True. With those details I managed to get the label I wanted on the Json file, which is perfect. So thanks for your help Patrick I appreciate it.